# Save a file created by fopen() function in php?

Tags: php, fopen

I have created a file, using fopen('contacts','w').
now i want to prompt user to save this file where he want in his local machine(using php).

Any suggestion or sample code will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: what do mean by local machine?

Comment: directory where he want to save file.I want to do same thing like  when we download a file then it prompt us to save the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file - "contacts" is a physical file exists now in the server.

```
<?php
$file = 'contacts.csv';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: it seems like what exactly i want, but my file is "contacts.csv" so what contact-type should i use for CSV file?

Comment: content type is fine. Just use the filename as contacts.csv. Edited the code.

Answer (score 2):

**Download code**

```
<?php

// place this code inside a php file and call it f.e. "download.php"
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path2file/"; // change the path to fit your websites document structure
$fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
        break;
        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;
// example: place this kind of link into the document where the file download is offered:
// <a href="download.php?download_file=some_file.pdf">Download here</a>
?>
```